# Filter array based on second array

Tags: php, arrays, array-difference

I have an array `$data` and it is required to be filtered based on another array `$clr`. I have done it by `foreach` and solved my purpose but I am looking for an optimum way like `map` or `filter`. What I have tried is:

```
$clr = [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 13, 21];
$data = [2, 3, 8];

foreach($clr as $val)
{
    if(($key = array_search($val, $data)) !== false) unset($data[$key]);
}

print '<pre>';
print_r($data);
```

Any of your suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: [array_diff](http://php.net/array_diff)

Comment: @SahilGulati should be `$data = array_diff($data,$clr);` you got the parameter order wrong

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Comment: you can use array_filter as well. have a look at https://3v4l.org/i53Ma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_diff($data, $clr);` [live demo](https://eval.in/789483).

Comment: I think `$data` should be first argument.